# Connect an LCD with Ribbon Cable to Breadboard

Tags: hardware, display, connection, connectors

I've purchased these two display modules, however, I am lacking the right connectors so that I can connect to my breadboard and to Pi.

I would like to know what hardware I should purchase for this interface.

[image: LCD display module]

[image: OLED Display module]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a 0.5mm pitch cable you could use this [flex cable breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1492).

If it is not 0.5mm pitch they have a [multi-pitch breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/products/1436)

Comment: How to connect the pitch cable with the board? Is a sticky tape sufficient?

Comment: I believe it is designed for you to solder on an Surface mount flex cable connector or solder the flex cable directly to the breakout. It might be possible to use Z-Axis Conductive Tape to connect it.